# How Do I Create Tables To Cross Join So They All Connect With The member_num

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys, ddl, create-table

My purpose is using these three tables and connecting them all together as they share a foreign key (member_num). I used auto-increment, therefor it wasn't in my code at certain points.

Volunteer Table:

```
create Table Volunteer(
member_num int not null auto_increment primary key,
firstname varchar(20) not null,
lastname varchar(20) not null,
dateofbirth date not null,
methodology varchar(40) not null,
langspoken varchar(10) not null default 'English',
langread varchar(10) not null default 'English'
);
```

Language Table (Read)

```
create Table VolunteerRead(
    member_num int auto_increment primary key,
    lang varchar(50) default 'English'
);
```

Language Table (Speak)

```
create Table VolunteerSpeak(
    member_num int auto_increment primary key,
    lang varchar(50) default 'English'
);
```

I am struggling and unsure how to connect them all into one table as I will be doing specific queries with them later on.

If anyone can help me, I am unsure if I need to use a join or a foreign key.

Any help helps, all the best.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you are not using the proper data structure for your use case. `member_num` is an auto-incremented key on all three tables, so there is no way to actually relate them.

Instead, you want foreign keys in tables `volunteer_read` and `volunteer_speak` that reference the primary key of `volunteer` (and you can have a surrogate primary key in those tables):

```
create table volunteer_read(
    id int auto_increment primary key
    member_num int references volunteer(member_num),
    lang varchar(50) default 'english'
);

create table volunteer_speak(
    id int auto_increment primary key
    member_num int references volunteer(member_num),
    lang varchar(50) default 'english'
);
```